# Phonegap developer on Ipad ios 8.4.1 is always in portrait orientation

Tags: cordova, ipad, ios8.4

I've downloaded the phonegap developer from the App Store to test my application on Ipad ( 4th generation ) with ios version 8.4.1 and the orientation doesn't seem to change to landscape mode and it's always in portrait mode.

I've checked if the Ipad was on orientation locked, but it wasn't and then i've downloaded the app from [build.phonegap.com](http://build.phonegap.com), the landscape orientation mode works as expected.

Downloaded the phonegap developer with Samsung Galaxy tab with android and tried to change it to landscape mode and it worked, so i thought that must be the phonegap developer with the Ipad or with this ios version ( 8.4.1 ).

Tried to change my `config.xml` file and tried to force the landscape mode

`<preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />`

but it continued to display the portrait orientation mode only.

So if anyone could give me more information about this issue or any possible solution i would be very much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: It was a bug on the phonegap developer app, it was created to work only on portrait mode. I was fixed a few days after you opened this question. https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-developer/issues/311.

Answer (score 0):

In the new `config.xml` write

```
<preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />
```

inside to

```
<platform name="ios">
```

Example for iOS:

```
<platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />
</platform>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set these preferences in **Xcode**. Select your `target` →  Click the `General` tab → Go to `Deployment Info` Section → Click `iPad` → Make your settings.

[image]